# How to improve cost of joined queries

Tags: mysql

I have a query in sql as below that takes 40 minutes to respond!

Any recommendations for tuning of this will be appreciated.

```
select    
      QA.*,
      QB.Tedade_Forushe_Ensheab 
   from
     ( ( SELECT
              dbo.MiladiTOShamsi(GETDATE()) AS CURENT_DATE, 
              '93/01/15' AS F_DATE, 
              '93/01/20' AS T_DATE, 
              E.title, 
              E.code as EsterCode,
              SUM( dbo.fn_ShamsiDateStrDiffDay( R.req_date, M.install_date )) AS TOTAL_DAY,
              COUNT(*) AS CNT,
              COUNT(R.req_seq) AS Req_seq_Count, 
              SUM( dbo.fn_ShamsiDateStrDiffDay( R.req_date, R.actv_date )) / COUNT(*) AS AVR_1, 
              SUM( dbo.fn_ShamsiDateStrDiffDay( R.visit_date, R.actv_date )) / COUNT(*) AS AVR_2, 
              SUM( dbo.fn_ShamsiDateStrDiffDay( R.pay_date, R.actv_date )) / COUNT(*) AS AVR_3, 
              SUM( dbo.fn_ShamsiDateStrDiffDay( R.visit_date, R.pay_date )) / COUNT(*) AS AVR_4, 
              SUM( dbo.fn_ShamsiDateStrDiffDay( R.req_date, R.visit_date )) / COUNT(*) AS AVR_5, 
              SUM( dbo.fn_ShamsiDateStrDiffDay( R.req_date, R.pay_date )) / COUNT(*) AS AVR_6, 
              SUM( dbo.fn_ShamsiDateStrDiffDay( R.actv_date, R.create_actv_date )) / COUNT(*) AS AVR_7,
              SUM( dbo.fn_ShamsiDateStrDiffDay( R.actv_date, M.first_date )) / COUNT(*) AS AVR_8
           FROM 
              tby_1_request AS R 
                 INNER JOIN y_1_tariff AS T 
                    ON R.tariff_type = T.tariff 
                 INNER JOIN tby_1_meter AS M 
                    ON R.cust_id = M.cust_id 
                 INNER JOIN tby_1_estr AS E 
                    ON R.estr = E.code
           WHERE
                  R.net_status = 3
              AND R.actv_date >= '93/01/15'
              AND R.actv_date <= '93/01/20'
              AND R.pay_date >= '93/01/15'
              AND R.pay_date <= '93/01/20'
           GROUP BY 
              E.title, 
              E.code ) AS QA

      left join
      ( Select 
              A.*,
              B.Tedade_Forushe_Ensheab,
              C.Tedade_Nasbfrom,
              D.Tedade_ijade_sabegeh 
           from
              ( select distinct Estr.title
                   from  tby_1_request Req
                      INNER JOIN tby_1_estr AS Estr 
                         ON Req.estr = Estr.code
                      INNER JOIN y_1_tariff AS T 
                         ON Req.tariff_type = T.tariff 
                      INNER JOIN tby_1_meter AS M 
                         ON Req.cust_id = M.cust_id
                   group by 
                      Estr.title,
                      Estr.code,
                      Req.pay_date,
                      Req.net_status,
                      Req.actv_date
                   having 
                          Req.net_status = 3
                      AND Req.actv_date >= '93/01/15'
                      AND Req.actv_date <= '93/01/20'
                      AND Req.pay_date >= '93/01/15'
                      AND Req.pay_date <= '93/01/20' ) AS A

      left join
      ( select
              Estr.title,
              COUNT( CASE WHEN Pay_date IS NOT NULL AND Req.pay_date >= '93/01/15' AND Req.pay_date <= '93/01/20' 
                          THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Tedade_Forushe_Ensheab
           from  
              tby_1_request Req
                 INNER JOIN tby_1_estr AS Estr 
                    ON Req.estr = Estr.code
           group by 
              Estr.title,
              Estr.code) AS B 
           ON A.title = B.title


      left join
      ( select 
              Estr.title,
              COUNT( CASE WHEN actv_date IS NOT NULL AND Req.actv_date >= '93/01/15' AND Req.actv_date <= '93/01/20' 
                          THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Tedade_Nasbfrom 
           from 
              tby_1_request Req
                 INNER JOIN tby_1_estr AS Estr 
                    ON Req.estr = Estr.code
           group by 
              Estr.title,
              Estr.code ) AS C 
           ON A.title = C.title


      left join
      ( select 
              Estr.title,
              COUNT( CASE WHEN create_actv_date IS NOT NULL AND Req.create_actv_date >= '93/01/15' AND Req.create_actv_date <= '93/01/20' 
                          THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ) AS Tedade_ijade_sabegeh
           from  
              tby_1_request Req
                 INNER JOIN tby_1_estr AS Estr 
                    ON Req.estr = Estr.code
           group by 
              Estr.title,
              Estr.code ) AS D 
           ON A.title = D.title ) AS QB 
       On QA.title = Qb.title
```

Comment: Yes. So what's your Question? Which one is the slowest part? With which part you need help to improve?

Comment: Q:  For your "tby_1_estr", is the "title" always unique per "code", or can there be multiple codes with the same title.  Could be a big review to simplify your query.

Comment: Also, your inner A-D queries don't reference your net_status.. was that intentional or not.  Or, SHOULD those other queries also consider the net_Status = 3 too?

Comment: Hopefully, and finally, is there only a single tariff per Request and only a single meter per request that would prevent duplicates and can eliminate your other A-D based queries.

Answer (score 0):

I edited your original SQL query for readability purposes only.  I re-adjusted, appeared to miss a double open paren for inner A-D left-join queries.

Additionally, without knowing table structures or available indexes, I would ensure on your tby_1_request table, you have an index on ( net_status, actv_date, pay_date ) to help on your WHERE criteria.  Also, for your B, C and D queries for counts, I would have individual indexes on (pay_date, estr), (actv_date, estr), and (create_actv_date, estr)

Looking a little closer, you are also getting a Cartesian result which is probably killing you as your queries are all grouped by title and code, but you are only joining on the title column.